# How do I reverse sort an arraylist in java? (ONLY using selection sort)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, selection, reverse

```
for (int i = 0; i <array.size(); i++){
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j++){
            if (array.get(j).getnumber() > array.get(min).getnumber()){
                min = j;
            }
        }

        object tmp = array.get(i);
        array.set(i, array.get(min));
        array.set(min,tmp);
    }
```

I think I might've made a mistake somewhere but I don't know where...

Comment: Use `Collections.sort(list, Comparator)`

Comment: sorry, but could you tell me a method using selection sort for this reverse sort...

Comment: Share the ArrayList definition, please.

Comment: not quite sure what u mean..

Comment: Your code is correct (it is selection sort in reverse order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't implement sorting like this way, JAVA provide us Comparable Interface to do this more effective

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{

private int number;

public Item(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}


public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}


public int compareTo(Item o) {
    //sort increasing
    //return  this.getNumber() - o.getNumber();

    //sort decreasing
    return o.getNumber() - this.number;
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<Item> list = Arrays.asList(new Item(3), new Item(6), new Item(-4));

            Collections.sort(list);

            for (Item item : list) {
                System.out.println(item.getNumber());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: tbh I haven't learnt collections yet..but thx for ur answer. sorry

Comment: @user2947725: you haven't learnt collections yet? What do you think ArrayList is if it's not a collection? What prevents you from learning by yourself? If you only ever use things that you have learnt in school, you won't get very far. Documentation exists for a good reason.

Comment: yeh I know, im not very smart.. :(, sry for wasting ur time

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to reverse sort some List `c` is `Collections.sort(c, c.reverseOrder())`. However, the elements of the List need to implement the `Comparable` interface. Alternatively, you can replace `c.reverseOrder()` with a separate comparator instead of implementing `Comparable`.

Comment: And if you already have a Comparator but want one that sorts in the reverse order, then use `Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator))`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way (and recommended way) of sorting ArrayLists is using the comparable interface or the Comparator object. These are very easy to grasp once you have done it a cople of times, but a bit confusing when you first start out. Here is an example of the Comparator object (untested, but I think it should work - assuming the objects in your array are of the type "MyCustomObject"):

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyCustomObject>();
myArrayList.add(new MyCustomObject(2));
myarrayList.add(new MyCustomObject(8));
myArrayList.add(new MyCustomObject(3));

// Here is the actual sorting:
Collections.sort(myArrayList, new Comparator<MyCustomObject>(){
    public int compare(MyCustomObject o1, MyCustomObject o2){
    if (o1.getNumber() > o2.getNumber()) return 1;
        if (o1.getNumber() < o2.getNumber()) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you want to change the sorting criteria, just change the implementation of compare() inside there - like reversing the if statements or sorting on a different field in your objects. If you're just reversing though, you should use reverseOrder() as mentioned by others in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Not tested

```
 int currentMax;
 int currentMaxIndex;

 for (int i = 0; i <array.size(); i++){

    currentMax = array.get(i).getNumber();
    currentMaxIndex = i;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j++){
        if (array.get(j).getnumber() < array.get(i).getnumber()){
            currentMax = array.get(j).getNumber();
            currentMaxIndex = j;
        }
    }

    // swap only if neccessary
    if (currentMax > array.get(i).getNumber()) {
        object tmp = array.get(i);
        array.set(i, array.get(currentMaxIndex));
        array.set(currentMaxIndex,tmp);
        // not sure how your object work, so not sure how this swap is working
        // so i just left it. 
    }

}
```